# How to determine if turtle is within a circle using xcor and ycor?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have an assignment that is asking us to draw a circle, return the turtle to the starting position, have the user move the turtle 10 times, evaluate if the turtle is within the circle and display a win/loss message.

We have to evaluate if the turtle is within the circle by using xcor and ycor, but I'm not sure how to calculate what's needed here.

```
#import turtle
import turtle

#declare variables
answer = str()
move_counter = int()
user_turn = str()
user_turn_num = int()
user_move = str()
user_move_num = int()

#establish turtle color and background color
turtle.pencolor("magenta")
turtle.bgcolor("black")

#ask the user what shape they'd like the turtle to be
print("Turtle has many shapes to choose from. Your options are classic, arrow, turtle, circle, square and triangle.")
answer = input("What shape would you like the turtle to be? ")

#if structure for changing the shape depending on the user's answer
if answer == "classic":
  turtle.shape("classic")
elif answer == "turtle":
  turtle.shape("turtle")
elif answer == "arrow":
  turtle.shape("arrow")
elif answer == "circle":
  turtle.shape("circle")
elif answer == "square":
  turtle.shape("square")
elif answer == "triangle":
  turtle.shape("triangle")

#bring turtle to circle location
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(100,-200)

#have turtle draw the circle
turtle.pendown()
turtle.fillcolor("magenta")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(100)
turtle.end_fill()

#return turtle to starting area
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0,0)

while move_counter < 10:
  #ask user if they'd like to turn
  user_turn = input("Which direction would you like to turn (left, right, neither)? ")
  
  #create if structure for turning
  if user_turn == "left":
    user_turn_num = int(input("Turn how many degrees to the left? "))
    turtle.left(user_turn_num)
  elif user_turn == "right":
    user_turn_num = int(input("Turn how many degrees to the right?"))
    turtle.right(user_turn_num)
  elif user_turn == "neither":
    print("No turn made.")
  
  #ask user if they'd like to move forward or backward
  user_move = input("Would you like to move forward or backward? ")

  #create if structure for moving forward or backward
  if user_move == "forward":
    #ask user how many spaces they'd like to move forward and move turtle that many spaces
    user_move_num = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move forward?" ))
    turtle.forward(user_move_num)

  elif user_move == "backward":
    #ask user how many spaces they'd like to move backward and move turtle that many spaces
    user_move_num = int(input("How many spaces would you like to move backward?" ))
    turtle.backward(user_move_num)

  #increment counter and let user know how many moves they have left
  move_counter = move_counter + 1
  print("You have", 10 - move_counter, "moves left.")

#determine if turtle is within the circle
xpos = turtle.xcor
ypos = turtle.ycor


#display win message
#display loss message

#make turtle exit on click
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `xpos = turtle.xcor` should be `xpos = turtle.xcor()`. Almost everything in turtle is a method. As for the circle, you could check if the distance between the turtle and the center of the circle is less than the circle's radius.

Comment: I suggest hardcoding your input values until the very end, after the program is working. `input()` makes it difficult to run your program, slowing down development and making it unclear to others what sort of values are sensible to enter.

Answer (score 1):

If `(x0, y0)` are the coordinates of the centre of the circle and its radius is `r`, it suffices to check:

```py
if ((turtle.xcor() – x0)**2 + (turtle.ycor() – y0)**2)**0.5 < r:
    # turtle is inside the circle
else:
    # turtle is not
```

i.e. distance from the turtle to the centre of the circle should be less than the radius (that is the definition of "circle").

Comment: Why not `turtle.distance(x0, y0) < r`